# Are permission requests required for Apple store apps?

Tags: ios, user-interface, permissions, app-store

I have custom built camera with AVFoundation and by default it does not ask permission. I also wish to get rid of permission request prompt to get users location to display it for them.

Most apps request these permissions, but I prefer to have my apps not do that. Is it required?

Answer (score 4):

Straight from the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).

> 4.1
> Apps that do not notify and obtain user consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data will be rejected

So my answer is YES you must obtain users permission if you're seeking Apple AppStore approval.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its compulsory.

The Permission alerts must be generated while using the stuff like Camera and all otherwise when you will try to use that stuff your app would crash.